# R function to filter rows that have numbers in the same decade

Tags: r

Having the following matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10]  [,11]  [,12] 
 [1,]   23   14   17   10     2     6    90    45    56     25     11      9 
 [2,]    1   15   18   21     2    26    35    50    81     33     61     93 
 [3,]    6   19   98   23    22     7     8    25    61     54     22     38
```

I want to get only the rows that have no more than 3 numbers in the same decade.
so the result must be:

```
[1] False
[2] True
[3] False
```

so finally we get only [2] that satisfies the condition. Can you please provide an R language function which can generate this result?

Regards, Dimitris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply`

```
m1[!apply(m1, 1, FUN = function(x) any(table(x %/%10) > 3)), , drop = FALSE ]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#[1,]    1   15   18   21    2   26   35   50   81    33    61    93
```